# C# comparing 2 lists of objects while ignoring the key field

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to compare 2 lists of objects for equality, but I want to ignore the key field.
How can I do this?

Here is an example:

```
public class myProduct
{
    int ID {get; set;}
    int field1 {get; set;}
    int field2 {get; set;}
}

<List>myProduct greenProducts = new <List>myProduct();
<List>myProduct purpleProducts = new <List>myProduct();

greenProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 1, field1 = 5, field2 = 8});
greenProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 2, field1 = 9, field2 = 12});
greenProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 3, field1 = 7, field2 = 7});

purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 8, field1 = 5, field2 = 8});
purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 9, field1 = 9, field2 = 12});
purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 10, field1 = 7, field2 = 7});
```

If you ignore the key field (aka the ID field), these lists are exactly the same.

So I want my code to do something like this:

```
if (purpleProducts == greenProducts) //I WANT THE ID FIELD IGNORED FOR THE COMPARISON SO RESULT WITH ABOVE DATA WOULD BE TRUE
{
  //DO ACTION HERE
}
```

Comment: Will the items be ordered? What if one list has duplicates ?

Comment: No order.  Lists will never have dupes.  That's actually what I'm working on is ensuring dupes never get introduced.  The tricky part for me is that the entire set of objects also needs to be reused.  There is a parent entity over the entities I describe above and if the entire list matches exactly I need to reuse it.

Comment: So it could be that these lists are in any order? If there is a wider use case you should detail it..

Comment: Yes, no specific order.  The ID field is just tied to the primary key in the database.  But it's just a unique identifier.

Comment: And there can never be dupes:   This can never happen:   purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 8, field1 = 5, field2 = 8});   purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 9, field1 = 5, field2 = 8});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no duplicates to worry about, elements could be in any order

```
if(
  green.Select(x => new { x.field1, x.field2 })
    .ToHashSet()
    .SetEquals(purple.Select(x => new { x.field1, x.field2 }))
)
```

We take your collections and project them to anonymous types of just the fields you want to compare. An anonymous type has built in equality logic based on the data contents of the properties, which saves you from having to override Equals and GetHashCode in your class (which would be another option). By turning one of the collections into a hashset you can then ask it if it equals the other collection. The other collection need not be a hashset.

A similar effect can be achieved with tuple, which also have built in equality checking

```
if(
  green.Select(x => (x.field1, x.field2))
    .ToHashSet()
    .SetEquals(purple.Select(x => (x.field1, x.field2)))
)
```

If you override Equals and GetHashCode on your class so that they declare equal purely based on field1 and field2 the code gets simpler:

```
if(green.ToHashSet().SetEquals(purple))
```

The overridden methods would look something like:

```
override bool Equals(object other) => other is MyProduct x && this.field1 == x.field1 && this.field2 == x.field2;
override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(field1, field2);
```

If you make your collections HashSet (with the overrides done above too) instead of List then they automatically dedupe themselves and the code is simply

```
if(green.SetEquals(purple))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I prefer the 2nd method that you supplied (overriding the equals).  It looks cleaner and easier to follow.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes linq queries get a little convoluted; breaking them over multiple lines or into multiple attempts can help but there is always merit in choosing appropriate collections (I'd use a hashset rather than a list for this case) and making the data classes a tiny bit smarter with things like being able to compare one to another on just some of the fields

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through it. Here is a loop that will make sure the number of duplicates are the same.

```
public class myProduct
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
}
List<myProduct> greenProducts = new List<myProduct>();
List<myProduct> purpleProducts = new List<myProduct>();

greenProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 1, field1 = 5, field2 = 8 });
greenProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 2, field1 = 9, field2 = 12 });
greenProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 3, field1 = 7, field2 = 7 });

purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 8, field1 = 5, field2 = 8 });
purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 9, field1 = 9, field2 = 12 });
purpleProducts.Add(new myProduct { ID = 10, field1 = 7, field2 = 7 });

var areEqual = true;
            
if (greenProducts.Count() != purpleProducts.Count()) areEqual = false;
if (areEqual)
{
    foreach (var item in greenProducts)
    {
        if(greenProducts.Where(g => g.field1 == item.field1 && g.field2 == item.field2).Count() != purpleProducts.Where(p => p.field1 == item.field1 && p.field2 == item.field2).Count())
        {
            areEqual = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (areEqual)
{
    //DO ACTION HERE
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
green.Zip(purple, (l,r)=>(l.field1 == r.field1) && (l.field2 == r.field2)).All(x=>x);
```

Comment: this is not as efficient as Beanz answer but is less typing :-)

Comment: I like the less typing.  I was wondering if C# had some kind of built in set or list comparison tool to do the job, but it seems like not.

Comment: Of course it does, you just haven't fully enough specified the problem yet..